# Error starting Spring Cloud Stream with Kinesis

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to start a new sample project using for process Kinesis Stream but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "-kinesis-consumer-1" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$5400(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$ShardConsumer.lambda$execute$0(KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:941)
```

And those are my pom dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.632</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The sample code of Spring Cloud with Kinesis is outdated, so I tried use newest dependencies.

Anyway, someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably try to use the latest Spring Boot `2.4.x` which brings for us Spring Integration `5.4` already. And this one is not compatible with the latest Spring Integration AWS, which is still based on the Spring Integration `5.3.x`.

Let's see if you still can stick with Spring Boot `2.3.x`!

Comment: Work like a charm! After changing the lib version the consumer started to... consume! Thanks a lot.